# NetBeans Web-Services Client Project - repeated WSDL parsing

Tags: java, netbeans, wsdl

I created a new project thus ...

```
  File, New Project...
    Java, Java Application.

  Right-click project icon in "Projects" tree-view panel.
    Choose New, Web Service Client...

  Specify WSDL file e.g. 
     ( ) Project
     (*) Local file D:\temp\Foo\Bar.wsdl
     ( ) WSDL URL                            [Set Proxy...]

     client-style JAX-WS

     [ ] Generate Dispatch code
```

It parsed the WSDL and generated lots of java files. I created a main class and used Netbeans to insert a WS client call

Now whenever I run my code (Desktop app), it again parses the WSDL (which doesn't ever change) and regenerates about 78 java files and compiles them.

How do I stop Netbeans performing this uneccessary and time-consuming action?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default netbeans behavior to guarantee the correctness of your proxy code. Although you must be able to change it. I guess it should be changed in the build.xml file (ant build script) to prevent this time consuming habit.